# How to return json with http code instead redirect Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#creating-form-requests) to incapsulate validation logic into files then to use it like:

```
   public function register(RegisterRequest $request) {}
```

When validation is false it redirects to the index page.

How to return json with http code instead redirection?

Comment: What are you using on front end axios, ajax ??

Comment: I send request using Postman in JSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From postman, you have to pass `Accept` as `application/json` on header tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use following code :

```
return \response($data, $statusCode);
```

for example :

```
return \response(['name'=>'Amin'], 200);
```